# django KeyError at (request)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am making a program and I have a small problem.
I'm currently designing a web page with python django and requests, and I have an Error which mentions That Key Error at 'main' and here are my codes

form:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput
from .models import City

class CityForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {'name' : TextInput(attrs={'class':'input', 'placeholder' :'City Name'})}
```

models:

```py
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
```

views:

```py
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import City
from .forms import CityForm

def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid=212c1f52ec8c8bbf34933937a6885114'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = CityForm()

    cities = City.objects.all()

    weather_data = []

    for city in cities:

        r =  requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

        city_weather = {
            'city' : city.name,
            'temprature' : r['main']['temp'],
            'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }

        weather_data.append(city_weather)
    context = {'weather_data' : weather_data, 'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'weather_data/weather.html', context)
```

I tried everything I could, and it didn't make it
I erased the 'main' part and any other things...
finally nothing worked.
I have an error message like this:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://codefair-tripple-wrbdv.run.goorm.io/

Django Version: 2.1
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'weather_data']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/workspace/CODEFAIR_TRIPPLE/project/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/workspace/CODEFAIR_TRIPPLE/project/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/workspace/CODEFAIR_TRIPPLE/project/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/workspace/CODEFAIR_TRIPPLE/project/weather_data/views.py" in index
  25.             'temprature' : r['main']['temp'],

Exception Type: KeyError at /
Exception Value: 'main'
```

Please help me!

Comment: You should check `requests.get(url.format(city)).json()` response before access to `r` because if that endpoint return empty then `'temprature' : r['main']['temp'],` might cause the issue unable to access `main` keyword like which you've got here

Comment: oh thanks I'll try it and tell you

Comment: ah...I just printed out and it mentions that {"cod":"404","message":"city not found"}

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: You could use this: ‘if r[“cod”] == “404”: continue

Comment: thanks alot!    if r['cod'] == '404': continue    worked!!!

Comment: That's a work around solution. I will give you an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After take a look at [the API](https://openweathermap.org/current), there are something you might need to take a look at the API response format and handle the failed cases.

First of all, you should handle in case your server unable to connect to API endpoint, there are a lot of situation which might led your server facing with errors. So, try to wrap your `requests.get` inside `try ... except` block, like so:

```py
try:
    r =  requests.get(url.format(city)).json()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
    # Handle incase you're unable to get the response
    continue
else:
    # Handle the successful case
```

Secondly, handle for successful request (inside `else` block):

```py
...
else:
    # Only handle successful cases
    if r.get('cod', 0) != "200":
        continue

    # Handle the rest as it is
```

---

After all,

```py
    for city in cities:
        try:
            r =  requests.get(url.format(city)).json()
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            # Handle request exceptions here
            continue
        else:
            if r.get('cod') != "200":
                # Ignore failed cases
                continue

            city_weather = {
                'city' : city.name,
                'temprature' : r['main']['temp'],
                'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
                'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
            }

            weather_data.append(city_weather)

    context = {'weather_data' : weather_data, 'form' : form}
```

Hope that helps!

There also one thing I just want to discuss with you about how fresh you want for your data? Is it required realtime data? Because that might eat up a lot of quota of your account to request weather API. If it's not, I think you could use `django cache` to cache the response so that you don't have to call it too frequently (I think that the weather won't change so fast)